# Scrolling does not work after redirect in reactstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a simple, petshop-like application in React. Its main functionality is managing articles. Recently I've experienced some weird behavior after trying to redirect client to a different route when a certain button is clicked.

So I have a button definition inside a reactstrap's modal window

```
render() {
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modalOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}
...
  <Button onClick={this.addNewArticle.bind(this)}>Add</Button>
...
```

It is meant to trigger a callback which will POST entered article data and then redirect client to a page where newly created article is displayed

```js
addNewArticle() {
    fetch('/api/v1/article', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state.articleData)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(article => {
        // ...
        this.toggleModal();
        this.props.history.push(`/read/${article.id}`);
    });
}

toggleModal() {
    this.setState({
        modalOpen: !this.state.modalOpen,
    });
}
```

Problem is, after the redirect is complete I'm not able to scroll through the article with the mouse wheel (calling `window.scrollByLines(1)` in devtools actually works). The whole page is just fixed in place. After I completely refresh the whole page (F5) everything seems to be back to normal and scrolling is enabled again. I've tried replacing `this.props.history.push` with returning `<Redirect />` tag inside the render() function, but it didn't help.

How can I prevent that weird scrolling lock?

**EDIT:** Added details about modal window.
It seems `toggleModal()` doesn't work as expected as it leaves the following CSS class in DOM, after redirect:

```css
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: React doesn't have anything to do with scrolling. You must have a DOM or CSS issue (or browser bug maybe? Does this happen in all browsers?). If we can see how your page/component is structured, that will help.

Comment: It reproduces in Firefox 77 and Chromium 83. I don't have any custom CSS definitions yet, I use the components from reactstrap

Comment: If you inspect the thing you expect to be scrollable, does it have any peculiar CSS styles that make it non-scrollable, maybe?

Comment: Oh, it seems it still has `.modal-open { overflow: hidden; }` after redirect (button is placed inside a Bootstrap's modal window). You must be right, problem is not in React itself but in Bootstrap

Comment: Good find. If you're still not sure how to fix, definitely add more details to your post like how you're using the modal.

Comment: Added some details. I'm still not sure how it fix it. It looks like the React has no time to update the DOM as it's immediately redirected after changing state.

Comment: Looks like a known, open bug: https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1819

Comment: It's a Bootstrap thing. I've found a similar issue on reactstrap's Github - https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1323 
It looks like that the issue is already fixed but not released yet. For now the dirty workaround with `document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-open')` seems to work. Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps you should post an answer to your own question; it'll sure help others to know your workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a known bug in reactstrap - https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1323

For now I have modified the addNewArticle code to remove the problematic element manually and the problem is gone

```js
...
.then(article => {
    ...
    this.toggleModal();
    document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('modal-open');
    this.props.history.push('/');
});
```